# ANDROID: How to call a method with arguments?

Tags: android, methods

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hello_world, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.new_task:
    newTask(null);
    return true;
    default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void newTask (View view) {whatever}
```

=====

How do I call newTask from the menu? Eclipse offered to add null argument.

Comment: Please refer to any basic tutorial on Android and/or Java.

Comment: This is not a very clear question. Take some time to revise it and make clear what you're trying to do, what you've already tried to do, and what exactly the problem is. Also take some time to read basic Java tutorials.

Comment: You can add a tag in your layout editor. However, as these guys are getting at, you might be better off putting the different things you want to do into separate methods and then calling those methods both from your newTask method and your onOptionsItemSelectedMethod

Comment: @DamonSmith, thank you, will try that. So basically will have to duplicate this method so that it can be called from within the class.

Comment: Yes but don't copy/paste it, just put the logic that you want called from both places into a new method and call that new method from both places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your newTask method is designed to be called by an onClick handler from a layout then you can add a tag to the view and then call view.getTag() inside your method.

That is one way that you could have many views call the same onclick handler method but then do different things.

Comment: Yes it is designed to be called by onClick from a layout. How and where do I add a tag to the view?

Comment: Sorry I deleted the answer then saw that you responded. So I replied to this above.